# AWS EC2 File Upload Using Http failing

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Java Spring Application that uploads files inside system **/tmp** directory temporarily.

My problem is 1. When I deploy my app on **AWS EC2 using Beanstalk** and try to upload files more than 1MB, the HTTP post request hangs and gives me **ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED**. I have allowed all Headers and Origins on my Spring Application.

When I test it on my local machine it works without a problem. but after

What I have tried is:

1. Allowing Headers and Origins on both client and server apps. Cors
2. Increased The Clients HTTP timeout

Still no luck the HTTP request is getting ABORTED.

Comment: Please share the code you are using and the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Turns out AWS Beanstalk runs on NGINX and Nginx default file upload size is 1MB, I have changed Nginx conf file under **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** added **client_max_body_size 100M;** under http.